# Flask: unable to serve rendered pages from specific directory

Tags: python, flask

I have a bunch of files in a directory that I wish to render and serve to the user, but have been unable to. Going to the path always returns just the `'page_template.htm'` and not the rendered file. Here's my code:

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, send_from_directory

# Instantiate the Flask app
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(__name__)
pages = FlatPages(app)

@app.route("/")
@app.route("/index")
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route("/Special_Data/<path:path>")
def page(path):
    page = send_from_directory('Special_Data', path)
    return render_template('page_template.htm', page=page)
```

What I wish to do is to grab raw text files from the `'Special_Data'` directory and to render them into html files so they look nice, then send them to the user if they click on a link.

The files are in the directory `'Special_Data'` and the `'page_template.htm'` is in the `'templates'` directory.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: `send_from_directory` is already the response which the endpoint should return in order to send a file. You don't have to pass the result to `render_template`. What exactly do you intend to do?

Comment: I’ve edited the question so it’s clear. I wish to take raw data from the 'Special_Data' directory, render it, then send it to the user. So ‘send_from_directory()’ would not be able to render the text data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following example shows you how you can use FlatPages to list, display and offer files for download. The markdown code is rendered beforehand and integrated into the specified or the default template.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template, send_file
from flask_flatpages import FlatPages
from io import BytesIO
import os

app = Flask(__name__)
# Optional configuration here!
pages = FlatPages(app)

# ...

# List all available pages.
@app.route('/contents')
def contents():
    return render_template('contents.html', pages=pages)

# Display the rendered result.
@app.route('/page/<path:path>')
def page(path):
    page = pages.get_or_404(path)
    template = page.meta.get('template', 'flatpage.html')
    return render_template(template, page=page)

# Download the rendered result.
@app.route('/download/<path:path>')
def download(path):
    page = pages.get_or_404(path)
    template = page.meta.get('template', 'flatpage.html')
    return send_file(
        BytesIO(str(render_template(template, page=page)).encode()),
        as_attachment=True,
        attachment_filename=f'{os.path.basename(path)}.html'
    )
```

templates/contents.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul>
      {% for page in pages %}
      <li>
        [<a href="{{ url_for('download', path=page.path) }}">Download</a>] - 
        <a href="{{ url_for('page', path=page.path) }}">{{ page.title }}</a>
      </li>
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

templates/flatpage.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>{{ page.title }}</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    {{ page }}
  </body>
</html>
```

pages/Special_Data/ncs1.html

```
title: Hello
published: 2010-12-22

Hello, *World*!

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
```

If you want to use a different template for rendering, you can define one within the metadata based on the file name. Add the following below published and a suitable template within the templates folder.

```
template: mytemplate.html
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it works! I have to ask: what if the data were is a sub-directory? Like pages/Special_Data/Subdirectory/ncs1.html?

Comment: @Legion As long as the files are in the directory specified via `FLATPAGES_ROOT` (default: 'pages'), the relative path to the file is extended (see `page.path` or the argument `path` in your route `pages`). So you can put a file in any directory tree within pages and it will be served. The reference by the path name would be: `pages/Special_Data/Subdirectory/ncs1.html` -> `Special_Data/Subdirectory/ncs1`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that `send_from_directory` sends the file to the client, it does not load it into memory. So your `page` variable is actually of type `Response` instead of `str` or a fileobject. If you want to read the file and than display it use

```py
import werkzeug

...

@app.route("/Special_Data/<path:path>")
def page(path):
    p = werkzeug.security.safe_join("Special_Data", path)
    with open(p, "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
       return render_template('page_template.htm', page=f.read())
```

Otherwise I'm afraid I can't help as I don't know what you want to do.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Just for my curiosity: what does the ‘ werkzeug.security.safe_join’ do?

Comment: @Legion Documentation for [`werkzeug.security.safe_join`](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/utils/#werkzeug.security.safe_join). Is your problem solved?

Answer (score 0):

Using `send_from_directory` Return a file to client.
So, you need to change like this

```py
@app.route("/Special_Data/<path:path>")
def page(path):
    return send_from_directory('Special_Data', path)
```

Or

```py
   return send_file(filename_or_fp=file_path, as_attachment=True, add_etags=True, conditional=True)
```

render_template will render your html template, it may return a html string. Therefore you need return file instead HTML string

Comment: I’ve edited the question so it’s clear. I wish to take raw data from the 'Special_Data' directory, render it, then send it to the user. So ‘send_from_directory()’ would not be able to render the text data.